# Django Celery: Task never executes

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

In my django application I am using celery. In a post_save signal, I am updating the index in elastic search. But for some reason the task gets hung and never actually executes the code:

What I use to run celery:

```
celery -A collegeapp worker -l info
```

**The Signal:**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=University)
def university_saved(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    University save signal
    """
    print('calling celery task')
    update_university_index.delay(instance.id)
    print('finished')
```

**The task:**

```
@task(name="update_university_index", bind=True, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=1, acks_late=True)
def update_university_index(instance_id):
    print('updating university index')
```

The only output I get is `calling celery task`. after waiting over 30 minutes, it doesn't ever get to any other print statements and the view continue to wait. Nothing ever shows in celery terminal.

**Versions:**
Django 3.0,
Celery 4.3,
Redis 5.0.9,
Ubuntu 18

****UPDATE:****
after doing some testing, using the `debug_task` defined inside the `celery.py` file in place of `update_university_index` does not lead to hanging. It behaves as expect. I thought maybe it could have been `app.task` vs `task` decorator but it seems that's not it.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(text, second_value):
    print('printing  debug_task {} {}'.format(text, second_value))
```

Comment: What's your celery version and OS?

Comment: 4.3 and ubuntu. I'll include them in the question.

Comment: I assume you have the worker running in paralell?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry, you have your application running and your worker on a separate terminal at the same time?

Comment: That is correct. `runserver` and `celery -A collegeapp worker -l info` are running in two separate terminals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still not sure as to why it doesn't work but I found a solution by replace `task` with `app.task`

importing `app` from my `celery.py` seemed to have resolved the issue.

```
from collegeapp.celery import app

@app.task(name="update_university_index", bind=True, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=1, acks_late=True)
def update_university_index(self, instance_id):
    print('updating university index')
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me once, I had made the dumbest error, django tells us to specify celery tasks in `tasks.py` file, and uses that for task discovery. After that it worked. Could you provide more insight into the directory structure using `tree` command?

This [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) is for `flask`, but the same can be achieved in django. Where this particular tutorial shines is that after you tell celery to execute a task, it also provides you with a `uuid` and you can `ping` that url and monitor the progress of the task you triggered.

Verify that the tasks have been registered by celery using (Do make sure that celery is running):

```py
from celery.task.control import inspect
i = inspect()
i.registered_tasks()
```

Or bash

```
$ celery inspect registered
$ celery -A collegeapp inspect registered
```

From https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#the-worker-isn-t-doing-anything-just-hanging

> Why is Task.delay/apply*/the worker just hanging?

> Answer: There’s a bug in some AMQP clients that’ll make it hang if it’s not able to authenticate the current user, the password doesn’t match or the user doesn’t have access to the virtual host specified. Be sure to check your broker logs (for RabbitMQ that’s /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit.log on most systems), it usually contains a message describing the reason.

Change this line

```py
@task(name="update_university_index", bind=True, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=1, acks_late=True)
def update_university_index(instance_id):
    print('updating university index')
```

To

```py
@task(name="update_university_index", bind=True, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=1, acks_late=True)
def update_university_index(self, instance_id):
    print('updating university index')
```

Or add `self` to the task definition.

Comment: I'll look into the link.
When I initially run celery, a list of all the tasks are generated. The  task is there so I do think its being discovered.

The tree structure is:

`collegeapp/university/tasks.py`

Comment: Could you verify by using the following while celery is running, I've updated the snippet to achieve that.

Comment: BTW Are you using docker for orchestration? Or running docker and celery separately?

Comment: I tried but it seems that `celery.task` does not have `control`. Maybe you're using an older version and it got deprecated?

Comment: I am not using docker.

Comment: Then I think you can directly use `$ celery inspect registered` or `$ celery inspect active`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216837/discussion-between-frozenone-and-paul-pierre).

Comment: Okay, I pinged you.

Comment: I tried running those commands but nothing happened

Comment: @PaulPierre Hope this helps https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#the-worker-isn-t-doing-anything-just-hanging

Comment: can you return to the chat? I tihnk I may have discovered something

Comment: Can you change function definition to -> `def update_university_index(self, instance_id):`

Comment: `TypeError: update_university_index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'` I get this

Comment: Hey in `celery v4.3`, they've introduced a `@shared_task` decorator -> https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.3.0/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-first-steps

Comment: @shared_task yields the same result. Hanging

Comment: I seem to have found somewhat of a solution. it works but I'm now noticing that celery does not execute all of the print statements in a specific task